# Liking to Pages on Facebook

Tags: facebook

This question has been answered but seems to be a little dated.

I have a "pages" account linked to my personal Facebook account. When I like something, I want it to appear on the pages account, not the personal (which I do not use but am required to have).

How do I do this?

Before answering, in regards to [How do "like" Facebook pages "as a Facebook page" rather than as my personal account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19432/how-do-like-facebook-pages-as-a-facebook-page-rather-than-as-my-personal-acc), the answer is not concise and none of the options appear on my phone when doing what is listed (possibly because it’s from 2011).

Comment: So is this a question about a Facebook smartphone app, then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using facebook from website then when you go to your page. There will a bar showing on top of the page.

[image]

In this bar you can switch back to your personal id and like any post.